# Problem with retriveing data from my database using JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I'am tring to retrieve from my database (using JPA) for a given list of items name their id,
my function wich called by my addFunction return just the id of the last item and ignore the rest!

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getListidItemByItemName()
  {
       try{
       EntityTransaction entityTrans=emm.getTransaction();
       entityTrans.begin();
          for (String val : listItem)  
          {
           System.out.println("my values"+val);
           javax.persistence.Query multipleSelect= em.createQuery("SELECT i.ItemId FROM Item i WHERE i.ItemName IN (:w)" );
           multipleSelect.setParameter("w", val);
           List ItemId =  new LinkedList();
           ItemId= multipleSelect.getResultList();
           listIdItem = new ArrayList(ItemId);
          }    
          entityTrans.commit();
          System.out.println("Id for given item name"+listIdItem);
          return listIdItem;
         }

         catch(Exception e)
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The result :

```
INFO: my valuesResponse Time
INFO: my valuesAssigned Group Response Time
INFO: Id for given item name[7]  //the id of the last item in the list

      return listIdItem;
  }
```

Where is the problem?

UPDATE:
I have use the solution of mat and it worked fine

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listIdItem = new ArrayList(ItemId);
```

This line replaces whatever you had in `listIdItem` with a new list. If you want to add to the `listIdItem` list, do something like:

```
listIdItem.addAll(ItemId);
```

Comment: Move the print inside the loop to see if you are really getting more than one id (print the ItemId list on each iteration).

Comment: @ Mat,yes your right when I have printed the item inside the loop I see know that the function works fine ,but the problem in my other funtion wich add those item into the database!

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting your variable `listIdItem` in every iteration of the loop with a new `ArrayList`. So in the end `listIdItem` will only contain the last iteration's values.